# Using MATLAB coder to export code from Registration Estimator app to C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-compiler, matlab-coder

Hi I'm trying to export "the default code" that is automatic generated from the Registration Estimator app within MATLAB to C++ using the `MATLAB Coder` tool.

This is an sample code I generated today:

```matlab
function [MOVINGREG] = registerImages(MOVING,FIXED)
%registerImages  Register grayscale images using auto-generated code from Registration Estimator app.
%  [MOVINGREG] = registerImages(MOVING,FIXED) Register grayscale images
%  MOVING and FIXED using auto-generated code from the Registration
%  Estimator App. The values for all registration parameters were set
%  interactively in the App and result in the registered image stored in the
%  structure array MOVINGREG.

% Auto-generated by registrationEstimator app on 21-Jun-2017
%-----------------------------------------------------------


% Convert RGB images to grayscale
FIXED = rgb2gray(FIXED);
MOVING = rgb2gray(MOVING);

% Default spatial referencing objects
fixedRefObj = imref2d(size(FIXED));
movingRefObj = imref2d(size(MOVING));

% Intensity-based registration
[optimizer, metric] = imregconfig('monomodal');
optimizer.GradientMagnitudeTolerance = 1.00000e-04;
optimizer.MinimumStepLength = 1.00000e-05;
optimizer.MaximumStepLength = 6.25000e-02;
optimizer.MaximumIterations = 100;
optimizer.RelaxationFactor = 0.500000;

% Align centers
fixedCenterXWorld = mean(fixedRefObj.XWorldLimits);
fixedCenterYWorld = mean(fixedRefObj.YWorldLimits);
movingCenterXWorld = mean(movingRefObj.XWorldLimits);
movingCenterYWorld = mean(movingRefObj.YWorldLimits);
translationX = fixedCenterXWorld - movingCenterXWorld;
translationY = fixedCenterYWorld - movingCenterYWorld;

% Coarse alignment
initTform = affine2d();
initTform.T(3,1:2) = [translationX, translationY];

% Apply transformation
tform = imregtform(MOVING,movingRefObj,FIXED,fixedRefObj,'similarity',optimizer,metric,'PyramidLevels',3,'InitialTransformation',initTform);
MOVINGREG.Transformation = tform;
MOVINGREG.RegisteredImage = imwarp(MOVING, movingRefObj, tform, 'OutputView', fixedRefObj, 'SmoothEdges', true);

% Store spatial referencing object
MOVINGREG.SpatialRefObj = fixedRefObj;

end
```

Within the Coder Tool in the section `Run-Time Issues` I received a couple of issues e.g. that coder need to [declare the extrinsic](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.extrinsic.html) . So far so good. I added for instance: `coder.extrinsic('imregconfig');`  and `coder.extrinsic('optimizer');`. But I still getting errors like:

> Attempt to extract field 'GradientMagnitudeTolerance' from 'mxArray'.
>
> Attempt to extract field 'MinimumStepLength' from 'mxArray'.
>
> Attempt to extract field 'MaximumStepLength' from 'mxArray'.
>
> ...

Pointing to the line with `optimizer.GradientMagnitudeTolerance = 1.00000e-04;` (and below).

I found out that usually the initialisation of variables is missing. But I don't know how to initialise the property `optimizer.GradientMagnitudeTolerance` in advanced. Can anyone help me with this?

PS: I'm using `MATLAB R2017a` and `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (C)` Compiler

Answer (score 0):

Based on the supported functions for code generation list at https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--categorical-list.html#bsl0arh-1, imregconfig is not supported for code generation. Which explains the issue you got first. Adding coder.extrinsic means that MATLAB Coder generated file will call into MATLAB to run that function. You can do this only for a mex target that needs MATLAB to run. imregconfig is not going to generate any C code. Standalone C code generation for use from external application is not possible with this code.

When functions declared as coder.extrinsic call into MATLAB they return an mxArray. The rest of the code can handle this mxArray only by passing it to MATLAB i.e. similar extrinsic functions. From Coder's point of view these are opaque types and hence the error about attempting extract fields from mxArray.

Comment: hmm thats bad :/ Do you suggest any other way to use this code "outsite" of the matlab IDE?

Comment: You can try MATLAB compiler to compile this code and create a standalone executable. That would run outside MATLAB.